PrestaShop theme development
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: some-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
    networks:
      - prestashop_network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  prestashop:
    container_name: prestashop
    image: prestashop/prestashop:8.1.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: some-mysql
      DB_NAME: prestashop
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWD: admin
    networks:
      - prestashop_network
    volumes:
      - /home/aicha/presta:/var/www/html
      

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin  # Use the same MySQL root password as in your MySQL service
      PMA_HOST: some-mysql
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: admin
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - prestashop_network

networks:
  prestashop_network:

volumes:
  dbdata:

I've set up Prestashop on Ubuntu using a Docker Compose file. After installation, a folder named 'presta' (as specified in the Docker Compose file) is created, containing the source code. However, it seems to be locked. I tried running some permission commands to gain access to the file and make some changes.
`sudo chown -R your_username:your_groupname folder_path
sudo chmod -R 755 folder_path
`
Next, I followed a tutorial on Udemy about creating a new theme. However, whenever I try to modify the code, I encounter a server error and I'm unable to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I initiated theme development by duplicating the /themes/classic folder, renaming it, and making changes in its theme.yml file. However, upon navigating to Design/Theme and Logo in the Prestashop back office, the server error page appeared.

The owner of the volume you mapped to /var/www/html should be www-data (with the group www-data). You shouldn't change ownership of these files. You can add your user to this group and then use 664 permissions for files and 775 for directories (www-data numeric id is 33 iirc). You can run the following in the folder that was created:
sudo find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sudo chmod 664 {}
sudo find . -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 775 

You can also use VSCode with the "remote" extension to connect to the site (via ssh) and edit the files remotely on a desktop (but will only be able to save any changes if you've done the above, of course). This has many other quality of life benefits!
In terms of theme development you would likely be better (for your first theme at least) creating a child theme (of classic) and working from there. There are quite a few changes between versions, so use the documentation for the major version you're using (Prestashop 1.7.x or Prestashop 8.x). I would strongly recommend not starting development on 1.7 as PrestaShop 9 is now being targeted for new features and 8 is only an evolutionary step from 1.7 (but with a better feature set).

Or sudo find . -exec chmod u-x+rwX,g-x+rwX,o-xw+rX {} + which does the same in a single sudo command and much faster.
